# How to set capturing groups to extract and replace with re.sub()

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re


#input_text_substring = "a partir de las 04:00 am 2022-09-02 hasta a las 04:15 pm 2022-09-04"
input_text_substring = "a partir de las 04:00 am 2022-09-02 fuimos a caminar hasta las 10 montanas, de alli hasta a las 04:15 pm 2022-09-04"


time_in_numbers = r"(\d{2})[\s|]*(?::|)[\s|]*(\d{2})[\s|]*(?:am|pm)"
date_in_numbers = r"\d{4}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}"
some_text = r"(.*?)" #any substring or no character (the condition will be set by the rest of the large regex)

regexp1 = r"(?:desde|apartir de|a partir de)[\s|]*(?:a esa de|a eso de|a|)[\s|]*(?:las|la|)[\s|]*" + time_in_numbers + r"[\s|]*(?:de|)[\s|]*" + date_in_numbers + r"[\s|]*" + some_text + r"[\s|]*hasta[\s|]*(?:a esa de|a eso de|a|)[\s|]*(?:las|la|)[\s|]*" + time_in_numbers + r"[\s|]*(?:de|)[\s|]*" + date_in_numbers

#Here you should place the capture groups obtained from the previous pattern
replacement1 = r"[(\2 \1)to(\5 \4)][\3]" #I need fix that!!

input_text_substring = re.sub(regexp1, replacement1, input_text_substring)


print(repr(input_text_substring))
```

The **output** with this format `'[(XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX (am|pm))to(XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX (am|pm))][some_text]'`, where `X` is any numeric character, that I need is something like this:

```
'[(2022-09-02 04:00 am)to(2022-09-04 04:15 pm)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 10 montanas, de alli]'
```

The problem I'm having is that it prints the original string directly without modifying it, since either this regex pattern doesn't work for this or the replacements with `re.sub()` are never done.

Comment: There still need to be some fixes, but one is for sure in `date_in_numbers`. the first number you want to catch is the year and it needs to be length 4: `r"\d{4}[\s|]...."`

Comment: it can show like this `'[(04 00)to(04 15)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 10 montanas, de alli]'` but if you want desire out so i can change the regex and try another method.

Comment: @Rabinzel You are right, there I corrected that, and at least modify some things `'[(00 04)to(15 04)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 10 montanas, de alli]'` , although it still does not give the correct result.

Comment: @Mehmaam Yes, I think the problem is in the replacement structure `replacement1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have a look if this pattern could be shortened or be more efficient, but a few small little chances were enough to get it working (at least for this example)

```py
#input_text_substring = "a partir de las 04:00 am 2022-09-02 hasta a las 04:15 pm 2022-09-04"
input_text_substring = "a partir de las 04:00 am 2022-09-02 fuimos a caminar hasta las 10 montanas, de alli hasta a las 04:15 pm 2022-09-04"


time_in_numbers = r"(\d{2}[\s|]*(?::|)[\s|]*\d{2})[\s|]*(am|pm)"
date_in_numbers = r"(\d{4}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2}[\s|]*-[\s|]*\d{2})"
some_text = r"(.*?)" #any substring or no character (the condition will be set by the rest of the large regex)

regexp1 = r"(?:desde|apartir de|a partir de)[\s|]*(?:a esa de|a eso de|a|)[\s|]*(?:las|la|)[\s|]*" + time_in_numbers + r"[\s|]*(?:de|)[\s|]*" + date_in_numbers + r"[\s|]*" + some_text + r"[\s|]*hasta[\s|]*(?:a esa de|a eso de|a|)[\s|]*(?:las|la|)[\s|]*" + time_in_numbers + r"[\s|]*(?:de|)[\s|]*" + date_in_numbers

replacement1 = r"[(\3 \1 \2)to(\7 \5 \6)][\4]" 

input_text_substring = re.sub(regexp1, replacement1, input_text_substring)


print(repr(input_text_substring))
```

Output:

```
'[(2022-09-02 04:00 am)to(2022-09-04 04:15 pm)][fuimos a caminar hasta las 10 montanas, de alli]'
```

Check out the pattern at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GABnOY/1)
The changes I made:

1. surround `date_in_numbers` with `()` to make it its own capturing group
2. make `(am|pm)` a capturing group by removing `(?:...)`
3. `time_in_numbers`- the two digits before and after the colon were its own capturing groups. Merged them together to be only one capturing group as a whole.
4. Adjust the groups in `replacement1`